# mysqli not accepting the ' character

Tags: php, mysqli

I am sending a post request from Android to php, everything works fine except if you use `'` character in the description field it doesn't work.

I have `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');` inside the PHP file and the collation of that description row is utf8mb4_bin. Any idea?

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8mb4');
$description = $_POST["description"];

$sql="INSERT INTO feed (fname,description,gender) VALUES(?,?,?);";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $fname, $description, $gender);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
echo "OK";
} else {
echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work __how__?

Comment: @u_mulder like I don't get any response back, I think it just doesn't execute the query

Comment: I don't see any response sending here. Also check your database, what is there?

Comment: ' is a special character. it needs to be escaped like \'

Comment: Is the query executing. Does it inserted the values

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry didn't add the whole code, it also does not echo failed. I just made new request with the following characters  !@#$%^&^^^^*(())___+++++;;;;...,,,<>>>||"``~~  It just works fine, except for the '

Comment: You REALLY need to turn on error reporting for mysqli to see why it does not execute the query. Add this to the TOP of your script: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: does your android app even call PHP? this code doesn't look to choke on a quote